# AWS: shared EFS between ec2-instance and lambda function using the same access point;

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

in AWS:

I am trying to share an EFS storage between EC2 instance and lambda function;
I have created an access point `ap-1` for EC2 instance at first:
Root directory path: /myapp/files

POSIX user:

User ID: 1234
Group ID: 1234

Root directory creation permissions
Owner user ID: 1234
Owner group ID: 1234
Permissions: 777

And it is working, I can move files, unzip files in the mounted EFS, after I mount the EFS to EC2 instance through this access point;

However, when I let the lambda function use this `ap-1`, it fails and with  `Error: EACCES: permission denied` when running `mkdir` command;

I did some search created another access point `ap-2` for lambda function:

Root directory path: /myapp/files

POSIX user:

User ID: 1000
Group ID: 1000

Root directory creation permissions
Owner user ID: 1000
Owner group ID: 1000
Permissions: 0777

And it works for the lambda function;
The key is that I need to set user `1000` in the access point for lambda function to use;

I figured that Both EC2 instance and lambda should use the same access point, since there is no need to use separate ones. So that I mounted the EFS to ec2 instance using `ap-2` instead of `ap-1`.

However, now EC2 instance is failing with  `Error: EACCES: permission denied` when running `mkdir` command in the EFS;

Question:

1. How can I mount EFS to EC2 instance and lambda function, using the same access point?
2. If I should use separate access points instead, is there any pitfalls when both party need to access and modify the same file in EFS?